# Add day to date with momentjs

Tags: date, momentjs

I am trying to add a day to my date:

```js
let createdDate = moment(new Date()).utc().format();

let expirationDate = moment(createdDate).add(1, 'd');

console.log(expirationDate);
```

However, this keeps returning an obscure object `{_i: "2017-12-20T21:06:21+00:00", _f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss Z", _l: undefined, _isUTC: false, _a: Array(7), …}`

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rLjQx/4982/

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are logging a moment object. As the [Internal Properties](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) guide states:

> To print out the value of a Moment, use [`.format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), [`.toString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-string/) or [`.toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/).

```js
let createdDate = moment(new Date()).utc().format();
let expirationDate = moment(createdDate).add(1, 'd');
console.log(expirationDate.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Please note that you can get the current date using [`moment()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now/) (no need to use `new Date()`) or [`moment.utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/).

Answer (score 3):

I will go with this one, simple works for me and I don't think you need other function to only add day in moment.

`var yourPreviousDate = new Date();
var yourExpectedDate = moment(yourPreviousDate).add(1, 'd')._d;`

Comment: How to add years from present date instead adding some days? @gem007bd

Comment: @MohdSadham it is really easy. You can follow this link.https://github.com/moment/momentjs.com/blob/master/docs/moment/03-manipulating/01-add.md and simple example is 'moment().add(7, 'y')' which will add 7 years to your current date.

Answer (score 2):

The `add` method modifies the moment object. So when you log it, you're not getting an obscure object, you're getting the moment object you're working with. Are you expecting a formatted date? Then use `format` or some other method.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with other answers just providing shortcut and different ways

You can do the format at the same time

```
moment().add(1,'d').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

or you can just format any date or date object

```
moment(result.StartDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```